# Semantic Ui Autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, semantic-ui

Good day I want to use this json data to use the autocomplete of semantic ui. any Idea please. below is my code I saw in different sites.

record.json

```
{
 records: [
      {
        idno: "PH00019404-1",
        firstname: "CHERRY MAE"
      },
      {
        idno: "PH00008381-2",
        firstname: "LUZMIN"
      }
 ]
}
```

My Html

```
<div class="ui search focus">
    <div class="ui search icon input">
        <input class="ui search" type="text" placeholder="Colors..." autocomplete="off">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.ui.search').search({
    apiSettings: {
        url: 'www.mysite.com/record.json',
        minCharacters : 3,
        onResponse: function(results) {    
            var response = {
                results : []
            };    
            $.each(results, function(index, item) {              
                response.results.push({
                    title       : item.idno,
                    description : item.firstname
                    //url       : item.html_url
                });
            });    
            return response;
        },
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: no result when I type to my textbox.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: also no error with the console.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this link. https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples

```
<script>
 $('.ui.search')
  .search({
   apiSettings: {
   url: 'http://localhost/views/api/members?q={query}'
  },
  fields: {
  results : 'records',
  description   : 'name',
  title : 'idno'
},
minCharacters : 3
})
;
</script>
```